# Plugin for Sending Email to Readers about New Posts? (besides "Subscribe2 ")

Tags: plugins, email, subscription

I wish to have a "subscribe to new posts" widget for my blog.

I know I can use feedburner system, but I want a plugin based solution.

The best I could find was [Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/), the downside of it is that you can't have it send full HTML e-mails for subscribers who are not registered users.

Is there any alternative plugin, or solution that can do this (maybe a work around based on the GPL subscribe2 plugin?)

p.s: the solution need to work with WP 3.  So the plugin [Subscribe2 for Social Privacy](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2-for-social-privacy/), that is supporting up to WP 2.6, is not a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best WordPress plugin for email subscriptions to your blog without using third party services like Feedburner is the [WP Responder Email Newsletter and Autoresponder Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-responder-email-autoresponder-and-newsletter-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

I really like G-Lock's [WP Double Opt-In List Management Plugin](http://www.glockeasymail.com/wordpress-email-newsletter-plugin-for-double-opt-in-subscription/). It has plenty of features for managing the subscriber list and options for customizing the email being sent out. Only issue I've had is that it pulls from the RSS feed, so I haven't figured out a way yet to include featured images in the email.